# Creating facebook events with api v2

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is possible to creating events with Facebook API?

It is possible in API v1:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/event#publish

But not in v2 (the current version):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event#publish

Can I use v1? is there some other way to creating Facebook events in a PHP app?

Answer (score 5):

If you have an app that was created before 4/30/14 you can use v1. But at 4/30/15 v1 will be deprecated and you will have to use v2.

Answer (score 3):

According to changelog for v2.0 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_games):
**Create event Removed** - Apps can no longer create events with the API.

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you check the V2 permissions page documentation by here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0  you will notice that the  Extended Permissions - Publish still exist after your app is reviewed and approved by Facebook.
Thus i beleive that if you get such approval to request publisch permissions to your users you can create events using the api.

This is my interpretation. It would be very helpfull if you could check that.

Comment: Did anyone tried this solution , i'm very new to android and got stuck to this similar problem . Also i'm trying some work around , if anyone wants to talk about it.

Comment: It seems pretty clear from [their permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-rsvp_event) that this is no longer possible:

_This permission does not let you create an event. There is no way to create an event through the API._