# Facebook backend create event

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, backend

I'm developping an android app and i need to create a facebook event from my app. 
I have done some search about that and i haven't found any thing on the grapgh APÏ to do something like that. I'm wondering if there is any way to create an event from my app. (With Adroid SDK ) or dicretly from my backend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apps can´t create events anymore, since v2.0 of the Graph API. You have to create events on Facebook, without the API.

More information:

- [Creating Facebook Event - Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102413/creating-facebook-event-graph-api)
- [Is there any way to create facebook event via API as graph api is no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545496/is-there-any-way-to-create-facebook-event-via-api-as-graph-api-is-no-longer-avai)
- [Creating facebook events with api v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498292/creating-facebook-events-with-api-v2)
- [creating event via facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778846/creating-event-via-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: Ok thanks do you have any info if there is a way to open a popup of facebook inside the app to create an event an fill some text ?

Comment: no, that´s not possible. you have to go to facebook.com if you want to create an event.